# OOP approach name when you override only private methods

Tags: oop

Could someone tell me the OOP approach name when you override only private methods? I would like to read more on it, but I do not know what to look for since I forgot the name of the approach.

The approach is about having only a single entry point in the base class in public methods, which in turn call virtual private methods which are overwritten by the children classes.

Comment: It's called OOP. Although, say, in Java, you cannot do that, instead you'd make them abstract.

Comment: @DaveNewton, oh. I am sure that this thing has its own name which is different from OOP. It is something like a style or a design solution. As far as I know mostly it is used in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Template method design pattern](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) (or, as Herb Sutter calls it, Non-Virtual Interface Idiom)

Comment: Yeah! Thank you a lot.